# yii2 createUrl is duplicating the route

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i'm building multi lingual site with English and Arabic

[url for English](http://localhost/multi/backend/web/site/index?val=hii&net=good)

[url for Arabic](http://localhost/multi/backend/web/ar/site/index?val=hii&net=good)

I want to switch language from any page exactly to the same page of the other language
so i made code like below.

```
   $route = Yii::$app->controller->route;
   $params = $_GET;
   array_unshift($params, '/'.$route);
```

---

```
  <?php if(Yii::$app->language == 'ar'){ ?>
  <?= Html::a('English', [Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl($params), 'language'=>'en']); ?>
  <?php }else{?>
  <?= Html::a('Arabic', [Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl($params), 'language'=>'ar']); } ?>
```

and my url generating like below

/multi/backend/web/en/multi/backend/web/ar/site/index?val=hii&net=good

[English](/multi/backend/web/en/multi/backend/web/ar/site/index?val=hii&net=good)

don't know what is wrong?

I'm using [this](https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls) for language management.

please check my **main.php** under backend/config

```
            <?php
            $params = array_merge(
                require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
                require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
                require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
                require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
            );

            return [
                'id' => 'app-backend',
                'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
                'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
                'language' => 'en',
                'sourceLanguage' => 'en_UK',
                'bootstrap' => ['log'],
                'modules' => [],
                'components' => [
                    'user' => [
                        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
                        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
                    ],
                    'log' => [
                        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
                        'targets' => [
                            [
                                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'errorHandler' => [
                        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
                    ],
                    'i18n' => [
                        'translations' => [
                            'app' => [
                                'class' => 'yii\i18n\DbMessageSource',
                                'sourceLanguage' => 'en_UK',
                            ],
                        ],
                     ],
                    'urlManager' => [
                        'class' => 'codemix\localeurls\UrlManager',
                        'languages' => ['en', 'ar'],
                        'enableDefaultLanguageUrlCode' => false,
                        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                        'showScriptName' => false,
                        'rules' => [
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'params' => $params,
            ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after lots of trying ..i found a solution.. now its worked for me.

```
    $route = Yii::$app->controller->route;
    if(Yii::$app->language == 'ar'){
        $_GET['language'] = 'en';
    }else{
        $_GET['language'] = 'ar';
    }
    $params = $_GET;
    array_unshift($params, '/'.$route);
```

---

```
  <?php if(Yii::$app->language == 'ar'){ ?>
  <?= Html::a('English', Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl($params)); ?>
  <?php }else{?>
  <?= Html::a('Arabic', Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl($params)); } ?>
```

its working for the url like

http://localhost/multi/backend/web/site/index?page=2&per-page=6

and

http://localhost/multi/backend/web/site/index

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing it as in your example, you have to think about it on every link you create. This can be automated easily.

#### URL-Rule

You can solve this with an url-rule in your config file like so:

```
'<language:[\w]{2,2}>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

This will assert the proper routing to your controller and provide you the desired language in the `language`-variable.

#### Custom UrlManager

You can extend the `UrlManager`-class and make sure the current language is always appended to the params:

```
class MyUrlManager extends \yii\web\UrlManager
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function createUrl($params)
    {
        if (!isset($params['language'])) {
            $params['language'] = Yii::$app->language;
        }

        return parent::createUrl($params);
    }

    // ...
}
```

This will automate the process of adding the language to the links you create.

#### Custom Application

Now you should also override the `Application`-class and always set the language to the one provided or choose a default (in this case `en`):

```
class MyApplication extends \yii\web\Application
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $lang = Yii::$app->request->get('language', 'en');
        Yii::$app->language = $lang;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now your language will always be set to the default value or the one provided viathe query param as specified above.

#### Final thoughts

This should give you the basic idea on how to solve your problem. Adjust as necessary...especially the last part with the `Application`-class and how you retrieve the value of the `language`-var. I hope it helped!

#### Possible problems with your code and the extension provided

If you read the docs of the extension the urls are generated differently. It tells you to create the urls as follows:

```
Url::to(['demo/action', 'language'=>'ar'])
```

You are createing a simple link-tag and overwrite the `$params`. Try this instead:

```
echo Html::a('Arabic', Url::to(['site/index', 'language'=>'ar']));
```

For redirection to the current page just replace the first part with the current route.

Comment: Then it should be even easier...take the code above and adjust it accordingly. As it seems this extension does exactly the same if your read their [feature-description](https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls#features). As you now extended your problem description with providing an extension and its configuration my answer is now obsolete...but it still gives you a good "behind the scenes" ;)

Comment: its working only the problem is i have two languages only.so i need a Arabic link when we are in English site and English link when we are in Arabic site.but the link is not generating urls in proper way.

Comment: but we cant predefine it..if we have slug and get values,pagination paramas.it will create problems..thats why i use createUrl function to dynamically create current url route.

Comment: Well...seems like there is another problem. In what way pagination and stuff is involved in this? Can you describe your use-case in detail?

Comment: `http://localhost/multi/backend/web/package/index?page=2&per-page=6`

then how i get this string `package/index?page=2&per-page=6`...also in the details page  `package/maldives-honeymoon-package`(slug)

Comment: simply add it in the `MyUrlManager::createUrl` as descibed in my answer! Check if this query param exists and if so add it to `$params` as I did with `$language`!

Comment: ya but i'm using this https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls ..please see the **urlManager** in my question.i think its already extend the default the **urlManager**